# Android: how create a button in my app that will take me to the App Manager

Tags: android

I'm looking to create a simple button in my android app that when clicked will take me to the app manager to a specific app where I can force close, uninstall, clear cache or data. Can someone help or point me to some examples to look at?

Answer (score 1):

[Use `ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS), with a `package:` `Uri` pointing to the app in question.

Note that this activity may not exist on all devices or may not be accessible by the current device user, so plan accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

start following activity in your button click event.

```
startActivity( new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS), 0);
```